# Get addresses of the owners of my tokens

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, tokens

Is it possible to issue a token and then send certain amount of ethereum to coin owners. For example is Alice owns 4 my token and Bob owns 6 of my tokens I want to send in total 10 Ethereums to my token owners, in this example Alice will receive 4 Ethereums and Bob 6 and I want to repeat this action every month. Can someone tell me if it is possible to make this kind of contract?
If it is possible I think there should be some global function, but unfortunately I couldn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contract cannot start a transaction of its own. You will need someone to start the transaction every month. But otherwise everything else should be possible.

Comment: Sure I can manage transaction every month manually but for example if Bob bought 5 tokens and then he resold it to Sally is it possible to send Ethereum to Sally and not to Bob?

Comment: @George That should be possible, you need to track amount of tokens for each user.

Comment: Can you please write the code which will give me all the wallets who currently owns my token?

Comment: You need at least two mappings `mapping (address => uint) balances; mapping (uint => address) addresses; uint index;`. When you add a new address you do something like this `addresses[index++] = msg.sender; balances[msg.sender] = balance;`. Then to know the addresses that have balance you use the `addresses` mapping. Be careful if your mapping have too many addresses it will use lot of gas.

Comment: Thanks I have understood the concept. Is it possible to save this data in swarm. As I know Swarm is storage for Ethereum contracts data.

Comment: Sorry, but you should ask a new question, I'm do not know enough about swarm to reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule execution in future with external tools such as

- Parity scheduler
- Ethereum Alarm Clock http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/

You will schedule for a specific block in future witch is quite accurate if you operate in terms of months at a specific day

Comment: Sounds interesting. Appreciate your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ethereum Alarm Clock](https://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/). To schedule transaction you can use:

1. [MyCrypto](https://mycrypto.com) wallet
2. [Chronos DAPP](https://app.chronologic.network)
3. [programmatical library @ethereum-alarm-clock/lib](https://github.com/ethereum-alarm-clock/lib)